# THREE.JS restrict movement (ограничить перемещение в изометрии)

Tags: javascript, three.js

Есть следующий пример [ссылка на codepen](https://codepen.io/artem-kochetkov/pen/ZEyxJxm). Как можно ограничить перемещение куба внутри окна?
есть похожий пример, [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902665/three-is-how-to-limit-pan-in-orbitcontrols-for-orthographiccamera-so-that-obje), но он не работает в изометрии.

update: немного ошибься в описании, нужно чтоб изначально объект был увеличенный, и не помещался в экран, при таче, чтобы можно было перемещать, но чтобы между края и моделью не было свободного места. (это планируется карта города).
Исходный код выглядит так

```js
const width = 700
const height = 300
const aspect = width / height

const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xCCCCCC);
scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(500))

const d = 1.1
let camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
    -d * aspect,
    d * aspect,
    d,
    -d,
    0.1,
    100,
)

camera.position.set(20, 20, 20)
camera.lookAt(scene.position)
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

const container = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(container);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setSize(width, height)
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.screenSpacePanning = true
controls.enableRotate = false
controls.enableZoom = false

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
cube.position.set(0, 0, 0)
scene.add(cube);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
    }

function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

animate()
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы же отключили вращение и зум камере, куда еще куб может выйти?

Comment: enablePan включен, я добавил
  controls.mouseButtons = {
    LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN,
    MIDDLE: THREE.MOUSE.PAN,
    RIGHT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN
}
теперь должно работать и с mouse

Comment: Я изменил на рабочий сниппет, добавьте ваши манипуляторы, пока не понятно оч чем речь. И зачем карту города помещать в 3д объект или что? Источников света нет тоже...

Comment: вот пример https://demos.littleworkshop.fr/infinitown
в нем карта бесконечная, и перемещение бесконечное, в моей карте будут границы, и я хочу ограничить перемещение в рамах карты, чтобы камера не уходила за ее пределы, все планируется работать в изометрии, пока пытаюсь поковырять тестовый вариант с обычным объектом

Comment: И что, какая связь? Там бесконечно блоками добавляются элементы при перемещении камеры. У вас камера не перемещается, зум не производится. Она всегда направлена в одну точки и опять же нет ничего похожего. OrbitControls нужны для демонстрации объекта в центре сцены, модели автомобиля, например. А здесь меняется высота камеры и положение камеры в горизонтальном пространстве.

Comment: хм, я знаком с three.js не больше недели, и с графикой у меня опыта 0, даже представления пока нету, как это правильно должно работать, у меня сейчас есть карта в увеличенном виде (zoom всегда фиксированный), я ранее делал с помощью mousemove и просто двигал ее с помощью методов translateX/translateY, но пока разбираюсь каким путем можно ограничить перемещение, в нужной проекции. если у кого-то есть возможность помочь с решением, я могу заплатить

Comment: и почему камера не перемещается? разве изменение camera.position.x/y/z не есть ее перемещение?

Comment: @артем Если знаете границы области, то ограничить перемещение можно с помощью метода [`.clamp()`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=vector3#api/en/math/Vector3.clamp)

Answer (score 0):

вообщем нашел некоторое решение которое работает при разных значениях zoom, сделал другой формат камеры и просто модифицировал модель изменив rotation, чтоб привести к изометрическому виду

камера:

```
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
  -this.d * this.game.aspect,
  this.d * this.game.aspect,
  this.d,
  -this.d,
  -5,
  100,
)

camera.position.set(0, 0, 5)
camera.zoom = 15
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
```

для модели подогнал вращение и взял по модели box

```
model.rotation.x = 0.5
model.rotation.y = -5.5
const bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(model)
```

в функции animate (тут есть костыли, так как небыло разобраться времени, но в моем кейсе в разных расширениях, зумах, устройствах это корректно работает), если есть желание - разбиритесь, поправьте - прокомментируйте

```
    const factor = camera.zoom
    const x1 = camera.position.x + camera.left / factor
    const x1a = Math.max(x1, bbox.min.x / 2)
    let pos_x = x1a - camera.left / factor

    const x2 = pos_x + camera.right / factor
    const x2a = Math.min(x2, bbox.max.x + bbox.min.x / 2)
    pos_x = x2a - camera.right / factor

    const y1 = camera.position.y + camera.bottom / factor
    const y1a = Math.max(y1, bbox.min.y - bbox.min.y / 2)
    let pos_y = y1a - camera.bottom / factor

    const y2 = pos_y + camera.top / factor
    const y2a = Math.min(y2, bbox.max.y - bbox.max.y / 2 - 0.04)
    pos_y = y2a - camera.top / factor

    camera.position.set(pos_x, pos_y, camera.position.z)
    camera.lookAt(pos_x, pos_y, controls.target.z)
    // orbitControls
    controls.target.x = pos_x
    controls.target.y = pos_y
    controls.update()
```